# How can I display vector correct?

Tags: c++, eclipse, function, vector

I have a little problem displaying my vector correct in C++.

It prints like this now:
Spiller navn: A
Score: 1

Spiller navn: A
Score: 2

Spiller navn: A
Score: 3

Spiller navn: B
Score: 1

Spiller navn: B
Score: 2
...
...and so on.

But i want it to print "Spiller" only once, and the "Score" multiple time, so it will look like this:

Spiller navn: A
Score:
  1
  2
  3

Spiller navn: B
Score:
1
2
3

Here is my fill vector function:

```
    void fyldVector(vector<Beregning>& nySpiller) {

string navn;
int score;


cout << "Indtast antal spillere: ";
int antal;
cin >> antal;

//nySpiller.reserve( nySpiller.size() + antal );

for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
    cout << "Indtast spiller navn: ";
    cin >> navn;

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cout << "Indtast score: ";
        cin >> score;

        Beregning nyBeregning(navn, score);
        nySpiller.push_back(nyBeregning);
    }
}
cout << endl;
}
```

And my print vector function:

```
    void printVector(const vector<Beregning>& nySpiller) {

unsigned int size = nySpiller.size();

cout << nySpiller.size() << endl;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {

    cout << "Spiller navn: " << nySpiller[i].getNavn() << endl;

    cout << "Score: " << nySpiller[i].getScore() << endl;

    cout << endl;
}
 }
```

Comment: I've seen that question before, and as far as i remember the answer was: _'Iterate over the vector in a loop, and output the items one by one'_!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not say what does function getScore and what is its return type then I use the function as it is used in your example.

```
void printVector( const vector<Beregning> &nySpiller ) 
{
   string navn;

   for ( const Beregning &b : nySpiller )
   {
      if ( navn != b.getNavn() )
      {
         navn = b.getNavn();
         cout << "\nSpiller navn: " << navn << endl;
         cout << "Score: " << endl;
      }   

      cout << b.getScore() << endl;
   }
}
```

If your compiler does not support the range based for loop then you can write

```
void printVector( const vector<Beregning> &nySpiller ) 
{
   string navn;

   for ( vector<Beregning>::size_type i = 0; i < nySpiller.size(); i++ )
   {
      if ( navn != nySpiller[i].getNavn() )
      {
         navn = nySpiller[i].getNavn();
         cout << "\nSpiller navn: " << navn << endl;
         cout << "Score: " << endl;
      }   

      cout << nySpiller[i].getScore() << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: AFAIR in the previous version of the question `nySpiller[i].getScore()` returned a vector (reference).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I have no definition of the return type.

Comment: Look here (might have been edited since then): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955416/how-to-include-array-in-vector

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks but I am not going to look there. It is the task of the athor of the question to provide all required information.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ The more important that I showed the method. All other are details.

Comment: It's _that particular detail_ the OP has problems with (as also stated in the question here).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ It is his problem. If he want to get details he has to provide information about these details.

Comment: I have tried your code, but get alot of errors, specially for the for-loop. I have tried to Iterate but don't know exactly to do it. I have tried all the methods from the another question, but it didn't work, so I startet from the beginning again with different methods.

Comment: What details do you need?

Comment: @user3340780 I need no details. I showed you code based on your example.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You saved my day. I can't give you upvote yet because I don't have reputation point.
But as soon I have I'ill upvote it. It works perfect now.
And thanks to you πάντα ῥεῖ for the help and good tips!

Comment: @user3340780 You can mark my answer as the best.